# provide custom location for inherited Spring context in Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a Spring application and a base test class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(name = "parent", locations = "/app-context.xml"),
    @ContextConfiguration(name = "child", locations = "/employee-context.xml")
})
public class EmployeeTests{
//...
}
```

and child test classes

```
@ContextHierarchy(
    @ContextConfiguration(name = "child", locations = "/manager-context.xml")
)
public class ManagerTests extends EmployeeTests{

}
```

but this seem to load configuration for both employee-context.xml and manager-context.xml 
I want the employee-context.xml configuration to have no effect in ManagerTests, but to have effect in other classes subclassed from EmployeeTests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can leave the EmployeeTests as it is and add this line to your ManagerTests

```
@ContextHierarchy(
@ContextConfiguration(name = "child",
locations = "/manager-context.xml",
 inheritLocations = false //add this line to your code
))
public class ManagerTests extends EmployeeTests{

}
```